# Finding Twitter users with follower count = MAX_FOLLOWER

Tags: twitter

I have been looking at finding Twitter users with followers more than MAX_FOLLOWER (any number set up by programmer).

I visited the twitter API and found I can search via q="keyword" but could not find any way where I can have a search in API using followers_count >= MAX_FOLLOWER

Tried looking some methods at https://dev.twitter.com/tags/finding-users as well but they were not really helpful as I could not find exactly what I am looking for.

Even for oAuth stuff, I tried creating a URL after creating a signature but still not able to consume that. [image]

[image]

From the signature base string if I copy the url and decode it for addreess bar and send the request it says page does not exist. So looks like I am not even able to consume the services properly.

My end result will be I want a list of users who have followers_count more than MAX_FOLLOWER and then I can do a new query on those users.

I have been trying this stuff for over 4-5 hours and totally clueless where I am doing wrong or how to proceed. Read a lot of twitter api docs but nothing I could find was useful in my case.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't appear possible. These two questions closely touch on what you're after and may point you to some alternative solutions: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701688/get-follower-count-on-twitter-api-search-results
2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063790/how-do-i-get-the-follower-count-for-thousands-of-twitter-users-per-hour-without